# How call a JS function on html?

Tags: javascript, html

i got that simple with just for exemple.

```
var app = {
    showModal: function() {
        alert('text');
    },
};
```

i tried that

```
<html>
<head>
<title>App</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a onclick="showModal()">Show</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried `app.showModal()`? That’s basic object property access.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = {
    showModal: function() {
        alert('text');
    },
};
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>App</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a onclick="app.showModal()">Show</a>
</body>
</html>
```

This should work